# Install debian package using cloud-init

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-init

I'm trying to install `netcat` using `cloud-init`.

As soon as I SSH'd to my vm, with all my keys configured correctly via `cloud-init` (meaning, it's executing), I try to run `netcat` and it doesn't work;

I'm using Container-Optimized OS (cos) as they refer to use it for `cloud-init`, and as of research I found cos is based on ChromiumOS kernel;

All I add to my cloud-init file is

```
packages:
 - nano
 - netcat
```

And none of them work.

Is there anything I'm missing to be able to add these packages?

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you want to run tools like nano and netcat interactively in that session, you can use the CoreOS toolbox in Container-Optimized OS to install and run these tools.

```
$ toolbox apt-get install -y nano netcat
$ toolbox nano
```

Comment: what about something like tmux

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't know why not. Go for it :-)

Comment: Toolbox doesn't seem to work unfortunately. I couldn't return to my tmux session